# How to create an app where I can click every path of an SVG image and change color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to create an app where I can click every path of an SVG image and change color in Flutter?

How to create an app where I can click every path of an SVG image and change color in Flutter? I need to create a coloring book app.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to load the svg and use a custom painter to paint the paths. To detect touch, you can use the [touchable](https://pub.dev/packages/touchable) package on pub.dev.

You should also maintain the currently selectedPath, in the custom painter and set the paint style to `PaintingStyle.fill` and you set the color to the required color.

A paint object looks like the below:

```
// your paint
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;
```

You could loop through the paths and where the path match the selected path, set the paint style to PaintingStyle.fill as shown below:

```
for (var path in paths) {
      // Here: archive our target, select one path/state, just change the paint's style to fill

      paint.style = path == selectedPath ? PaintingStyle.fill : PaintingStyle.stroke;

      // some other code
    }
```

You can check the github repo https://github.com/mastersam07/click for a guide on how to do such. I have created something similar, where the svg is clickable and colors the selected path and effect another widget.